# Why is my woocommerce shortcode appearing at the top of the page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On my product page, I have removed the related products section:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
```

So I can add it back to a different part of the page via shortcode.

My shortcode simply called the function `woocommerce_output_related_products` and worked perfectly until a recent update caused it to throw an error.

The error was that for some reason it wasn't able to access the global variable `$product` anymore.

So to my shortcode function I added:

```
global $product;
if( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
}
woocommerce_output_related_products();
```

This fixed the error and now renders the products again, however in puts them at the very top of the page instead of where the shortcode is located.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a shortcode you need to return the content not echo it, the `woocommerce_output_related_products` function echos. You can use `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` to return instead.

```
global $product;
if( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
}
ob_start();
woocommerce_output_related_products();
return ob_get_clean();
```